# Error : The type Class is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T>

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am using Blackberry plug in for eclipse.
Default jre setting is 1.6
I am getting following error which doesnt allow me to compile my .java file :

The type Class is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Please help.

Comment: Please post the source code and the full error message. Else all answering remains only guess work.

Comment: The error is not displayed on the console.
The package declaration statement gives the error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes for J2ME projects must be compiled to be version 1.3 compliant.
=> no generics, enums, extended-for .....

But it should fix your problem :)

Comment: I commented the enum statement in my class and the error disappeared ...
I need to use enums in the java file.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You can do it the old fashioned way and use constant values :)

Comment: No. JavaME uses an old version of the Java language that predates enums and generics. You simply can't use them at all.